# Primefaces Lightbox work only once time per once image?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, lightbox

Primefaces Lightbox works only once per image selection.

I have two images on one page

1) Lightbox opens when clicking on image 1.

2) Lightbox does not open when you click on image 1 again.

3) Lightbox opens when clicking on image 2.

4) Lightbox does not open when you click on image 2 again.

but it works on IE.

p.s. I use Chrome and I declared `<f:view contentType="text/html">`

```
<p:lightBox styleClass="imagebox"> 
    <h:outputLink value="#{LoxCtrl.staffInfoStaffPhotoShow}" title="#{LoxCtrl.staffInfoStaffNameShow}">  
        <p:graphicImage value="#{LoxCtrl.staffInfoStaffPhotoShow}" style="border-style: ridge;" height="170px"/>
    </h:outputLink>   
</p:lightBox>
```

Comment: What is `{LoxCtrl.staffInfoStaffPhotoShow}` returning ? Please tell me the exact `String` you are getting for one of the values returned by `{LoxCtrl.staffInfoStaffPhotoShow}`

Comment: return full path of image etc. http://www.abc.com/image/001.jpg

Comment: and `abc.com` is from the net? You shouldn't hotlink images to your app. It's bad practice, but I'm not saying that's the cause of your issue. Can you post the entire `xhtml` ?

Comment: not yet hotlink ... but it is data from select data from DB and put to list ... string is file name (001.jpg) and i concat url ... etc. staffInfoStaffPhotoShow = "http://www.abc.com/image/"+fileName; ... ps. abc.com is it sample data

Comment: I see. I'll take another look.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with just this code sorry. I would need to see more of the xhtml file.

Comment: Hi Andy Thank you for your help .... it's work now ... i don't know why it's work -*- ... but it's work already

Comment: maybe because i change primeface 3.4 to 3.5 on tomorrow